# How Do You Implement UpdatePanel Functionality Using .Net Core 3

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-core, updatepanel

My .Net Core 3 application has a need where I want to only refresh certain sections of page without affecting the other page sections. Here is a high level view of the page (Issue/Edit):
[image]

The general operation is as follows. A user selects an issue they want to edit. There are a number of attributes that they can change. When they are done making changes, there is a save button at the bottom to submit their changes. On the Edit page there are 2 partial views. One allows the user to add/update status information for the issue (we maintain all status information) using a modal pop-up. The other section allows a user to Upload/Edit/Delete files that they want attached to the issue using a modal popup.

When a user changes the status or files, that data is saved immediately to the database. Currently I refresh the entire Issue/Edit page because I want to reflect those changes after they are saved. The concern is that any changes made to any other field on the form is lost. One option is to pass the forms data around and run a save on the entire issue when I save the status or file info. This seems like a huge overhead since I would be resaving the entire issue multiple times when not needed and I'd have to handle the passing of all of that data. The other option is to find a way to ONLY refresh partial view that was interacted with.

Here is a stripped down version of the Edit page:

```
    @model MYAPP.ViewModels.IssueViewModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Issue Detail Page";
}

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
    });
   
</script>

<div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger"></div>
<hr />

<div class="row">
    <div>
        <form asp-action="Edit">
            <input type="hidden" asp-for="IssueData.issueId" />
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div>
                <table style="width:100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td style="background-color:midnightblue;color:white;padding-left:5px;">
                            <label class="control-label">Issue Title</label>
                            <img src="~/Images/pencil1.png" width="20" height="20" />
                            <input id="title" class="title" type="checkbox" onclick="onSelectChange(this)" style="position:relative;left:-24px; opacity:0" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input asp-for="IssueData.issueTitle" class="form-control formtableborders" id="titletext" disabled="disabled" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="IssueData.issueTitle" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <table style="width:100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td style="background-color:aquamarine;padding-left:5px;">
                            <label asp-for="IssueData.issueContext" class="control-label"></label>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <textarea asp-for="IssueData.issueContext" class="form-control formtableborders" rows="3">IssueData.issueContext</textarea>
                <span asp-validation-for="IssueData.issueContext" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>

            <div id="modal-container" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1">
                <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="status">
                @{
                    await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_Status");
                }

            </div>

            <br />
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="@Model.IssueData.correctiveActionIdentified"></label>
                <input asp-for="@Model.IssueData.correctiveActionIdentified" class="correctiveActionIdentified" type="checkbox" />
            </div>            
            
            <div id="UploadSection">
                @{
                    await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_DisplayFiles");
                 }

            </div>
            <br />
            <div class="form-group">
                <table style="width:100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td style="background-color:midnightblue;color:white;padding-left:5px;">
                            <label asp-for="IssueData.keyword" class="control-label"></label>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <input asp-for="IssueData.keyword" class="form-control formtableborders" />
                <span asp-validation-for="IssueData.keyword" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Save Changes" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>

</div>
<script>

</script>
<div>
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
    <script>
         $(document).ready(function () {
            var JumpTo = '@ViewBag.JumpToDivId';
            if (JumpTo != "") {
                $(this).scrollTop($('#' + JumpTo).position().top);
            }
        });

        $('body').on('click', '.modal-link', function () {
            var actionUrl = $(this).attr('href');
            $.get(actionUrl).done(function (data) {
                $('body').find('.modal-content').html(data);
            });
            $(this).attr('data-target', '#modal-container');
            $(this).attr('data-toggle', 'modal');
        });

        $('body').on('click', '.relative', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var form = $(this).parents('.modal').find('form');
            var actionUrl = form.attr('action');
            var dataToSend = form.serialize();
            $.post(actionUrl, dataToSend).done(function (data) {
                $('body').find('.modal-content').html(data);
                var isValid = $('body').find('[name="IsValid"]').val() == 'True';
                var issueid = "";
                issueid = $('body').find('[name="issueidSaved"]').val();                
                var jumpto = $('body').find('[name="jumpto"]').val();
                if (isValid) {
                    $('body').find('#modal-container').modal('hide');
                    if (issueid != "") {
                        window.location.href = "/Issue/Edit/?id=" + issueid + "&jumpto=" + jumpto;
                    } else {
                        window.location.href = "/Issue/Edit";
                    }
                }
            });
        })

        $(function () {
            $('body').on('click', '.fileupload', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var form = $(this).parents('.modal').find('form');
                var actionUrl = form.attr('action');

                var fdata = new FormData();
                $('input[name="file"]').each(function (a, b) {
                    var fileInput = $('input[name="file"]')[a];
                    if (fileInput.files.length > 0) {
                        var file = fileInput.files[0];
                        fdata.append("file", file);
                    }
                });
                $("form input[type='text']").each(function (x, y) {
                    fdata.append($(y).attr("name"), $(y).val());
                });
                $("form input[type='hidden']").each(function (x, y) {
                    fdata.append($(y).attr("name"), $(y).val());
                });
                $.ajax({
                    url: actionUrl,
                    method: "POST",
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false,
                    data: fdata
                }).done((response, textStatus, xhr) => {
                    var isValid = $(response).find('[name="IsValid"]').val() == 'True';
                    var issueid = $(response).find('[name="issueidSaved"]').val();
                    var jumpto = $(response).find('[name="jumpto"]').val();
                    if (isValid) {
                        $('body').find('#modal-container').modal('hide');
                        window.location.href = "/Issue/Edit/?id=" + issueid + "&jumpto="+jumpto;
                    }

                   });
            })
        });

        $('body').on('click', '.close', function () {
            $('body').find('#modal-container').modal('hide');
        });

        $('#CancelModal').on('click', function () {
            return false;
        });

        $("form").submit(function () {
            if ($('form').valid()) {
                $("input").removeAttr("disabled");
            }
        });
    </script>
}
```

Here is the _DisplayFiles:

```
<table id="upload" width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td width="90%" style="padding:5px 5px 0px 5px;background-color:midnightblue;color:white">
            <label class="control-label">Upload Attachments</label>
        </td>
        <td style="background-color: midnightblue; padding-right:5px">
            <a href="@Url.Action("FileUpload", new { controller = "Attachment", issueid = Model.IssueData.issueId  })"
               class="modal-link btn btn-success">Upload Files</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table width="100%" border="1" class="tblAttachments">
    <tr align="center">
          <th width="20%" style="text-align:center">File Name</th>
          <th width="75%" style="text-align:center">Description</th>
          <th width="5%" style="text-align:center"></th>
    </tr>
    @for (var i = 0; i < Model.IssueData.AttachmentList.Count; i++)
    {
    <tr>
        <td style="padding-left:3px">@Model.IssueData.AttachmentList[i].aFileName</td>
        <td style="padding-left:3px">@Model.IssueData.AttachmentList[i].aIssueAttachmentDescription</td>
        <td style="text-align:center">        
              <a href="@Url.Action("DownloadFile", new { controller="Attachment" , attachmentId=Model.IssueData.AttachmentList[i].attachmentId })" class="fa fa-download "></a>
              <a href="@Url.Action("EditFile", new { controller="Attachment" , 
                      attachmentId=Model.IssueData.AttachmentList[i].attachmentId,
                      aFileName=Model.IssueData.AttachmentList[i].aFileName,
                      issueId=Model.IssueData.AttachmentList[i].issueId,
                      aIssueAttachmentDescription=Model.IssueData.AttachmentList[i].aIssueAttachmentDescription})" class="modal-link  fa fa-pencil "></a>
              <a href="@Url.Action("DeleteFile", new { controller="Attachment" , 
                      attachmentId=Model.IssueData.AttachmentList[i].attachmentId, 
                      aFileName=Model.IssueData.AttachmentList[i].aFileName, 
                      issueId=Model.IssueData.AttachmentList[i].issueId })" class="modal-link  fa fa-trash "></a>
              @*<button type='button' title='Download' style='background:transparent;border:none' asp-action="DownloadFile" asp-controller="Attachment"
                      asp-route-attachmentId="@Model.IssueData.AttachmentList[i].attachmentId">
                  <i class='fa fa-trash'></i>
              </button>*@
        </td>
    </tr>
      }
</table>
```

Here is the _DeleteFiles:

```
<!--Modal Body Start-->
<div class="modal-content">
    <input name="IsValid" type="hidden" value="@ViewData.ModelState.IsValid.ToString()" />
    <input name="issueidSaved" type="hidden" value="@ViewBag.ID" />
    <input name="jumpto" type="hidden" value="@ViewBag.JumpToDivId" />
    <!--Modal Header Start-->
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title">Delete File</h4>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
    </div>
    <!--Modal Header End-->

    <form asp-action="DeletetheFile" asp-route-attachmentid="@ViewBag.id" asp-route-issueId="@ViewBag.issueId" asp-controller="Attachment" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"
          data-ajax="true" data-ajax-update="#UploadSection">
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        <div class="modal-body form-horizontal">
            Are you sure you want to delete the @ViewBag.title File?
            <!--Modal Footer Start-->
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button data-dismiss="modal" id="cancel" class="btn btn-default" type="button">No</button>
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success relative" id="btnSubmit" data-save="modal" value="Yes">
            </div>
            <div class="row">
            </div>
            <!--Modal Footer End-->
        </div>      
    </form>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {

    });
</script>
<!--Modal Body End-->
```

Here is the controller code for the _DeleteFiles

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult DeleteFile(int attachmentId, string aFileName, string issueId)
{           
    ViewBag.id = attachmentId;
    ViewBag.title = aFileName;
    ViewBag.issueId = issueId;
    return PartialView("_DeleteFile");
}

[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult DeletetheFile(int attachmentid, string issueId)
{ 
    string response = _adoSqlService.DeleteAttachment(attachmentid);
    ViewBag.ID = issueId;
    ViewBag.JumpToDivId = "upload";
    IssueViewModel IVM = new IssueViewModel();
    IVM.IssueData = new IssueDataModel();
    IVM.IssueData = _adoSqlService.GetSingleIssue(issueId);
    return PartialView("_DeleteFile");
}
```

The way the above works is the Issue/Edit page loads and the _DisplayFiles partial view is populated with a list of files. The user selects the DELETE button and the Javascript on the Edit page opens the modal and populates it with the _DeleteFiles partial view. When the user selects "yes" to delete the file, the "DeletetheFile" code is run. This sets some viewbag data before the POST is intercepted by the javascript on the Edit page again. This time the javascript captures some values populated by the Viewbag and ViewData before refreshing the entire Edit page so it reflects the file has been deleted.

I'd like to be able to ONLY refresh the _DisplayFiles partial view instead of the whole page. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

I found my answer at the following url: [Update an MVC Partial View With AJAX](https://cmatskas.com/update-an-mvc-partial-view-with-ajax/).
I ended up surrounding the partial view with a div:

```
<div id="partialContent">
    //Partial View Data
</div>
```

Then in some javascript on the page I added the code to load when ajax intercepts the submit from the partial view:

```
$("#partialContent").load('/Controller/Action');
```